# Accounting for intersecting features with spatial join?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, spatial-join, overlapping-features

I am looking to analyse the effects of the designation Marine Conservation Zones (MCZs) on fishing effort. I have a shapefile for fishing effort which is gridded, each pixel has information about fishing effort, and a shapefile containing the MCZs (see picture below)

[image: Black boxes represent MCZs, the red line is the country border, blue squares represent effort, with greener squares showing higher effort]

The issue is as follows. I want to create a layer which has rows with each of the MCZs then columns with the total effort, total number of vessels etc. I have managed to do this by using spatial join, with the MCZs as the target feature and Fishing effort as the join feature and intersect as the match option. However when a pixel is partly in and partly not in the MCZ then the pixel is not accounted for in the output. So for example the output after spatial join for the MCZ at the top registers zero fishing effort, as no pixels are fully within it.

Is there a way to add effort to the MCZ relative to the proportion of a pixel that is within it?

So, using the MCZ at the top again, say that 20% of the pixel lies in the MCZ and the pixel has an effort of 10 units. Ideally I would want the output to display 2 units of effort for this particular MCZ.

Comment: Convert each Pixel to a Polygon, https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012696